# QWidget native window switching

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating QWidget and setting

```
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true);

  setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true);
```

but sometimes I need to disable it and I' setting (on button click)

```
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, false);

  setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, false);
```

but without result. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: we probably need to see more of the code around where you disable the attributes. Perhaps hiding then showing the window again will cause it to take effect?

Comment: no I can't hide window or something like that.
Are this WA_PaintOnScreen and WA_NativeWindow flags depending on other flags?

Comment: If I remember right, you **have to** hide and show the window to see these effects. Just call `hide()` (or `close()`)and `show()` directly after another, this should work.

Comment: no it's not working.. I'm setting 



hide();

setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, false);

  setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, false);

show();

but without result.

Comment: Which platform are you on?